# C++ GLUT Как передать метод класса в в glutDisplayFunc (без "invalid use of non-static member function")

Tags: c++, glut

Здравствуйте я использую GLUT и C++.
У меня есть класс App с методом Render, и я хочу его передать в glutDisplayFunc, но при попытках:

```
glutDisplayFunc(App::Render);
```

или

```
glutDisplayFunc(this->Render);
```

Возникает ошибка "invalid use of non-static member function".

Можно ли и если да то как передать метод Render в glutDisplayFunc?

Comment: никак, только если передать статический метод и из него вызвать метод для конкретного объекта...

Comment: Я так и сделал, но это не очень хорошо.

Comment: можешь обернуть класс в какой-нить вкусный паттерн вроде одиночки — будет поприличней... и вызов к `glutDisplayFunc` оберни в вызов к методу своего класса...

Comment: Хардкорный подход - генерировать эту функцию в рантайме, встраивая в нее значение указателя на экземпляр класса-обработчика и вызывая соответствующий метод этого класса.

Comment: @VTT, ради интереса, можно пример такого хардкора?